# Unreal Engine 5 Puzzle Example Block Spacing has no effect

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I've recently begun toying with Unreal Engine (UE5 Early Access) and I started with the Puzzle Example Template. In the `PuzzleBlockGrid` blueprint, there is a variable called `BlockSpacing` that is used to calculate the (X,Y) coordinates a block before spawning it.

This is the blueprint.
[image]
[image]

I collapsed the logic for calculating the position to tidy up the graph a bit. I've highlighted the path to the variable in question.

Changing the value of `Block Spacing` has no effect on the placement of the blocks. I have verified this by printing the calculated values to the screen (not shown in pictures). I have tried changing `Block Spacing` to a wide range of values (10^10, 1, 0, 10^-10, -100: Default was 400). No matter the value entered, the calculated values are always the same. The only way I could get a different result is to bypass the `Block Spacing` and `Multiply` nodes; in which case, all positions are calculated to be (0,0).

Am I missing something?

Just FYI the calculated coordinates that I get are:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that this is happening because `Block Spacing` is public and the value was set in the level map's viewport editor details pain, which overrides the initial value set in the blueprint.

[image]